# Problems using debuild to upload a python/GTK program to Launchpad

Tags: python, package, debian, dpkg, launchpad

[update, I found the solution, see answer below]

I made a GUI wrapper for protonvpn, a cmd program for Linux. `dpkg -b` gets me [ProtonVPNgui.deb](https://www.byteshift.de/msg/launchpad/ProtonVPNgui.deb), which works fine. However, I have problems using `debuild -S -sa` to upload it to [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/%7Ebnmm/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages).

1. As is, it won't build once uploaded with `dput`, cf. the [error msg](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/509768566/buildlog_ubuntu-focal-amd64.protonvpngui_1.1%7Efocal_BUILDING.txt.gz)
2. I tried using `debuild -i -us -uc -b` to build a .deb file for local testing, but it returns:

   `dpkg-genchanges: error: binary build with no binary artifacts found; cannot distribute`

Any ideas? This whole process is driving me nuts. (I use this [tar.gz](https://launchpad.net/%7Ebnmm/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+sourcefiles/protonvpngui/1.1%7Efocal/protonvpngui_1.1%7Efocal.orig.tar.gz))

[image: Text]

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out myself. Create a .deb package locally for testing and upload the project to Launchchpad:

1. Create a launchpad user [account](https://help.launchpad.net/YourAccount/NewAccount).
2. Install dh-python with the package manager
3. Create the package source dir

   `mkdir myscript-0.1`
4. Copy your python3 script(s) (or the sample script below) to the source dir (don't use `!/usr/bin/python`, use `!/usr/bin/python3` or `!/usr/bin/python2` and edit accordingly below)

   `cp ~/myscript myscript-0.1`

   `cd myscript-0.1`

   Sample script:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/python3

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       print("Hello world")
   ```
5. Create the packaging skeleton (debian/*)

   `dh_make -s --createorig`
6. Remove the example files

   `rm debian/*.ex debian/*.EX debian/README.*`
7. Add eventual binary files to include, e.g. gettext .mo files

   `mkdir myscript-0.1/source`

   `echo debian/locales/es/LC_MESSAGES/base.mo > myscript-0.1/source/include-binaries`
8. Edit debian/control

   Replace its content with the following text:

   ```
   Source: myscript
   Section: utils
   Priority: optional
   Maintainer: Name, 
   Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 9), python3, dh-python
   Standards-Version: 4.1.4
   X-Python3-Version: >= 3.2

   Package: myscript
   Architecture: all
   Depends: ${misc:Depends}, ${python3:Depends}
   Description: insert up to 60 chars description
    insert long description, indented with spaces
   ```
9. debian/install must contain the script(or several, python, perl, etc., also eventual .desktop files for start menu shortcuts) to install as well as the target directories, each on a line

   `echo myscript usr/bin > debian/install`
10. Edit debian/rules

    Replace its content with the following text:

    ```
    #!/usr/bin/make -f

    %:
        dh $@ --with=python3
    ```

    Note: it's a TAB before dh $@, not four spaces!
11. Build the .deb package

    `debuild -us -uc`

    You will get a few Lintian warnings/errors but your package is ready to be used:

    `../myscript_0.1-1_all.deb`
12. Prepare upload to Launchpad, insert your gdp fingerprint after -k

    `debuild -S -sa -k12345ABC`
13. Upload to Launchpad

    `dput ppa:[your ppa name]/ppa myscript_0.1-1_source.changes`

This is an update to [askubuntu.com/399552](https://askubuntu.com/questions/399552/how-to-create-a-deb-package-for-a-python3-script). It may take some error messages and googling till you're ready... C.f. the ...orig.tar.gz file at [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/%7Ebnmm/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages) for the complete project.